# Add new excel sheets with a for loop in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop

Following problem: each iteration of a for loop a new sheet to an existing excel workbook should be added. in the same iteration a pandas series has to be written into this sheet. At the end there have to be one excel file with multiple sheets each containing one pandas series. I was trying by:

```
from pandas import Series
for counter in range(n):
   sheet_name = 'Sheet%s' % counter
   series.to_frame(name = '').to_excel('output.xls', sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Unfortunately, this code generates a new excel workbook each iteration. As a result, there is only one sheet in there. Please help, I have absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), you can pass in an existing ExcelWriter object:

> If passing an existing ExcelWriter object, then the sheet will be
>   added to the existing workbook. This can be used to save different
>   DataFrames to one workbook:
>
> ```
> >>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
> >>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
> >>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
> >>> writer.save()
> ```

So, this should work:

```
from pandas import Series, ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter('output.xls')
for counter in range(n):
   sheet_name = 'Sheet%s' % counter
   series.to_frame(name = '').to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

writer.save()
```